# Setting Margin from C# code

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, margin

I want to set the margins of different controls using C# code-behind (I know how to do it in XAML markup).

I need it for controls like rectangle or buttons.

Answer (score 10):

```
myControl.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, right, bottom);
```

or

```
myControl.Margin = new Thickness(allSideMarginSize);
```

should do it.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.borderthickness.aspx